# Json response from ADO.Net model with Nancy

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, nancy

I have a Nancy app with ADO.Net models, I'd like to return some objects like:

```
 Get["/getById/{id:int}"] = _ =>
            {
                int id = _.id;
                User user = EntityContext.Users.Find(id);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    return Response.AsJson(user);
                }
                return "User not found with Id: " + id;
            };
```

The generated User.cs is the following:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace NancyApplication1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string profile_image { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }

        public virtual UserType user_type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code generates an empty response body, any idea what's wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We need a bit more to go on. What's the type of user? How does your route and route handler look? How are you testing?

Comment: Stop returning models directly from entity framework. Arg.

Comment: Then what should I return, @Phill ?

Comment: A response object or view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option in my opinion is to use ApiModel classes for your API responses.

Create a class (you also might not want to return password in your API):

```
public class UserApiModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string profile_image { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

Get an [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) library, configure it in application bootstrapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserApiModel>();
```

And then in your controller add:

```
var model = Mapper.Map<UserApiModel>(user);
```

Automapper will copy all values to a model class object, which will be returned properly. 
You also don't have write Response.AsJson(user). Nancy will return JSON if you set ContentType header correctly in your API request, simple

```
return model;
```

will be enough.